# What is the "boost_interprocess" folder in iCloud "Documents"?

Tags: icloud, finder, folders, quarkxpress

While cleaning up old files I've found an empty "boost_interprocess" folder in my **iCloud "Documents"** folder (it's really empty: checked in Terminal).

Any idea what this folder is for - a quick search seems to find a lot of references to this folder in Windows and [one answer on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54757122/boost-interprocess-folder-appearing-in-mac-documents-folder), but I'm mystified as to what created this?

I'm on OS X Mojave 10.14.4, MacBook Pro.

Answer (score 1):

### QuarkXPress creates a "boost_interprocess" folder

I've just found the answer. This folder can be created for several process, but in this case it's QuarkXPress, as outlined in this [QuarkXPress support post](https://support.quark.com/en/support/solutions/articles/19000099215-un-identified-folder-boost-interprocess-creation-under-documents-on-mac-os).